# Логирование ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, логирование, ffmpeg

Как сделать логирование выполнения конвертации в `ffmpeg` вызывая через `exec`?

Мне на выходе нужно получить файл, прочитав который я смогу понять, что конвертация файла `1.mp4` завершена успешно, или наоборот, произошла ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто проверь exit code после исполнения ffmpeg, если 0 всё ок

Comment: Для полноты ответа хорошо было бы показать минимальный рабочий пример

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ готовый пример кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149933)

Comment: **проверь exit code после исполнения** - это неверно. Читаем man на функцию exec: *The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.* Это означает, что ВОЗВРАТ из функции exec происходит только в том случае, если запуск программы, заданной первым аргументом НЕВОЗМОЖЕН.  Если же новый процесс успешно запушен, то возвращаться уже некуда - он ведь ВЫТЕСНИЛ текущий процес.

Comment: @Sergey, вы не тот man открыли. exec в php - это не сисколл exec в линуксе http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

Comment: Ну, если этот так, то TS стоило бы поставить тэг PHP в своём вопросе.

Comment: Имеете ввиду так? 

<?php
exec('ffmpeg -i video_origine.avi -target pal-vcd video_finale.mpg', $output, $return);

// Return will return non-zero upon an error
if (!$return) {
    echo "Конвертировано";
} else {
    echo "Не конвертировано";
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

Я бы просто заменил

```
execl("Script.sh", NULL);
```

на

```
system("Script.sh > logFile.txt");
```

И всё...